# On the proof that the total variation of a signed measure is itself a (positive) measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a signed measure $\nu$ on $(X,\mathcal{M})$, define
[image]
[image]

Here is the first half of the proof in Stein and Shakarchi's *Real Analysis*:

> [image]

**Question:**

Could anyone elaborate the last sentence of the proof above? Why the inequality is immediate by taking the supremum?

---

In Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, similar argument is given. But I don't understand why it is so quick. It seems to me though one should instead let
$$
a_j=|\nu|(E_j)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2^j}
$$
which would give the desired result by taking the summation and using the last inequality in the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible interpretation I come up.

Suppose one wants to prove that for two quantities $A$ and $B$
$$
A\leq B.
$$
One shows that for any $t<A$, one has $t\leq B$. This is the same as

> for any $\epsilon>0$, $A-\epsilon\leq B$.

Namely, $B$ is an upper bound for the set $$\{A-\epsilon\mid \epsilon>0\}.$$ By taking the supremum on the set,
one concludes that $A\leq B$.

---

Alternatively (and more directly), since $B$ is the upper bound for the set
$
\{t\in\mathbb{R}\mid t<A\},
$
and the supremum of this set is $A$, one can conclude that
$$
A\leq B.
$$

Comment: I was so obsessed with Terry Tao's [epsilon-of-room trick](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/245a-problem-solving-strategies/) and I didn't realize that the last step in Stein-Shakarchi is indeed very quick (and of course equivalent to the $\epsilon$ one).